# Setting parents in tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, huffman-code

I have a huffman binary tree that starts with an empty node a.

A points to a left node and a right node, which also point to left and right nodes. Is it possible to set the parent nodes for each node recursively after having this tree?

This is the code I am thinking:

```
public Node setParents(Node n)
{
    if(n.getZero() == null && n.getOne() == null)
    {
        return n;
    }
    Node a = setParents(n.getZero()); // Zero being left
    a.setParent(n);
    Node b = setParents(n.getOne()); // One being right.
    b.setParent(n);
}
```

Here is how I am currently creating the tree by using a priority queue with values sorted least to greatest.

```
public Node createTree(PriorityQueue<Node> pq)
{

    while(pq.size() > 1)
    {
        Node n = new Node();

        Node a = pq.poll();
        if(pq.size() > 0)
        {
            Node b = pq.poll();
            n = new Node(a.getFrequency() + b.getFrequency());
            n.setZero(a);
            a.setWhich(0);
            a.setParent(n);
            n.setOne(b);
            b.setWhich(1);
            b.setParent(n);
        }
        else
        {
            n = new Node(a.getFrequency());
            n.setZero(a);
            a.setWhich(0);
            n.setParent(n);
            n.setOne(null);
        }
        pq.add(n);
    }
    Node n = pq.poll();
    n.setParent(null);
    setParents(n.getZero());
    setParents(n.getOne());
    return n;
}
```

I just need to make sure each node has a parent, which I don't know where to start from here.. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Some comments to your code that may help

1 . Do not use getters and setters in your study samples for simple assignments and reads, they are hard to understand.

2 . If you prepare some object do not mix this preparation with others

```
        n.setZero(a);
        a.setWhich(0);
        a.setParent(n);
        n.setOne(b);
```

3 . From what I understand there is a chance to get NPE

```
          if(pq.size() > 0) {
              Node b = pq.poll();
          }
     }
     Node n = pq.poll();
     n.setParent(null);      <-  n can be null
```

4 . Java has nice feature called Enums for this

```
     a.setWhich(0);
     b.setWhich(1);
```

---

Here is how to set parents starting from the root

```
public void fixParents(Node parentNode)
{
    if (parentNode.zero != null) {
        parentNode.zero.parent = parentNode;
        fixParents(parentNode.zero);
    }
    if (parentNode.one != null) {
        parentNode.one.parent = parentNode;
        fixParents(parentNode.one);
    }
}
```

**UPD**

One more thought. You set parents in your tree building function. So you should just check that parents are correct but not re-setting them.

```
public void checkParents(Node parentNode) throws Exception
{
    if (parentNode.zero != null) {
        if (parentNode.zero.parent != parentNode) {
            throw new Exception( here include info about the parentNode.zero );
        }
        checkParents(parentNode.zero);
    }
    if (parentNode.one != null) {
        if (parentNode.one.parent != parentNode) {
            throw new Exception( here include info about the parentNode.one );
        }
        checkParents(parentNode.one);
    }
}
```